# Is there a way to get sum of five-minute increments and the average every 25 minutes from those 5-minute increments in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with like this:

```
LocationNumber  Date              Sales
0   8744    2022-02-01 18:57:34    18       
1   3986    2022-02-01 15:55:26    15       
2   5489    2022-02-02 11:51:29    11       
3   1578    2022-02-03 14:30:37    14       
4   6457    2022-02-01 15:25:52    15
```

I want something that firsts converts this into 5-minute sales. And then a column that have the average per 25 minutes.

```
             Date       Five_minute_sales    25_minute Average
108 2023-03-01 09:00:00       2.0                0
109 2023-03-01 09:05:00       9.0                0
110 2023-03-01 09:10:00       6.0                0
111 2023-03-01 09:15:00      19.0                0
112 2023-03-01 09:25:00      69.0                21
```

I tried the pd.grouper function But I need something that can get me an average for multiple stores without the number being too high.

Comment: please make your output match the input and ensure to provide enough data per store to have a meaningful example

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of `df.resample("5T").sum().rolling("25T").mean()`

Comment: I tried that but does not work for different days with different time increments.

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="5T"))["Sales"].sum()
df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="30T", origin=pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 08:55:00"), label="right"))["Sales"].mean()
```

And then :

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).fillna(0)
```

I have tried with this df as input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[8744, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:01:34"), 18],  [3986, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:02:26"), 15],  [5489, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:03:29"), 11], [1578, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:04:37"), 14], [6457, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:05:52"), 156], [3986, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:06:26"), 21],  [5489, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:07:29"), 34], [1578, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:08:37"), 14], [6457, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:09:52"), 25], [8744, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:11:34"), 18],  [3986, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:12:26"), 15],  [5489, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:13:29"), 11], [1578, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:14:37"), 14], [6457, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:15:52"), 156], [3986, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:16:26"), 21],  [5489, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:17:29"), 34], [1578, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:18:37"), 14], [6457, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:19:52"), 25], [8744, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:21:34"), 18],  [3986, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:22:26"), 15],  [5489, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:23:29"), 11], [1578, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:24:37"), 14], [6457, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:25:52"), 156], [3986, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:26:26"), 21],  [5489, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:27:29"), 34], [1578, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:28:37"), 14], [6457, pd.Timestamp("2023-03-01 09:29:52"), 25]], columns=["LocationNumber", "Date", "Sales"])
```